# Как происходит обработка hook_menu и передача данных на коллбек-функции в drupal?

Tags: drupal, post, php

Пишу модуль для Drupal.
Суть: от внешнего сервера приходит POST на мой [урл](http://www.mysite/cart/payment-sent) ,
где информация пишется в бд и выводится.
Согласно логам сервера посылающего запрос, пост содержит кучу полей.
Однако на странице пусто (не считаю pre), а в бд пишется '0'.
Вопрос:

Как происходит обработка hook_menu и передача данных на
коллбек-функции в drupal ??

Есть подозрение, что именно тут теряются данные.

```
function upc_menu() {
$items['cart/payment-sent/'] = array(
    'title' => 'Статус платежа',
    'page callback' => 'upc_notify',
    'page arguments' => array($_POST),
    'access callback' => 'can_user_see_result',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
}

function upc_notify($post) {
    db_query("UPDATE {variable} SET value = '%s' WHERE name = '%s'", "test_upc_POST1", print_r($post, true));
    variable_set('test_upc_POST2', $post);
    print('some text<pre>');
    print_r($post);
    print('</pre>');
}
```

Comment: @Iranda  
Садись, 2.  
Слово [ОДНАКО][1] в начале предложения не бывает вводным, а значит, не выделяется запятыми.  
В начале простого предложения, в том числе в составе сложного, ОДНАКО  
является   союзом, по значению равным НО. (Не будете же вы после НО ставить  
запятые!)  
Зато в середине простого предложения или в его конце ОДНАКО выступает в роли  
вводного - и должно быть выделено запятыми, то есть обособлено.
Верни как было
  [1]: http://lik-bez.com/publ/9-1-0-9

Comment: @zenith, спасибо. Все исправлено. Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

В общем всё оказалось интереснее.
Не смотря на то, что

```
'page arguments' => array($_POST),
```

фактически аргументы передаваемые в обработчик upc_notify, **POST так в drupal`е не передают!**
Правильная реализация:

```
function upc_menu() {
$items['cart/payment-sent/'] = array(
    'title' => 'Статус платежа',
    'page callback' => 'upc_notify',
    'access callback' => 'can_user_see_result',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
}

function upc_notify() {
    db_query("UPDATE {variable} SET value = '%s' WHERE name = '%s'", "test_upc_POST1", print_r($_POST, true));
    variable_set('test_upc_POST2', $_POST);
    print('some text<pre>');
    print_r($_POST);
    print('</pre>');
}
```

То есть, обращение идёт напрямую к глобальной переменой.
Не знаю как другим, а для меня это нечто среднее между белочкой и шизой.
Drupal отстой.